# "in the event of failure" VS "in the event of a failure"

Tags: indefinite-article

> 1. In the event of failure, the machine will first react based on the self-diagnostic software.
> 2. In the event of **a** failure, the machine will first react based on the self-diagnostic software.

Do we need the indefinite article "a" here? And which one should I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends more on personal style and context than grammar.  Both are idiomatic.  "Failure" represents the uncountable concept of failure, while "a failure" represents a specific instance where something has failed.  You can choose whichever makes more sense in that particular context, or whichever sounds better to you.

On a side note: "Failure" may not be the correct word for the subject matter, as it can imply something has *failed* in the structure or in the design.  In software, when something goes wrong it is called an *error*, and are usually not a problem when they are properly *handled* (as it sounds like in your example).

This can also apply when talking about a physical device.  The machine might *throw a warning/error* in performing some task, which then the embedded software will handle.